# How can I get the name of friends?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables like these:

```
// users
+----+----------+
| id |   name   | 
+----+----------+
| 1  | John     |
| 2  | Peter    |
| 3  | Martin   |
| 4  | Barman   |
| 5  | Jack     |
| 6  | Ali      |
+----+----------+

// friends
+-----------+---------+
| friend_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------+
| 2         | 1       |
| 5         | 1       |
| 1         | 3       |
| 2         | 3       |
| 5         | 3       |
| 2         | 4       |
| 1         | 5       |
| 4         | 5       |
+-----------+---------+
```

And this is expected result:

```
+-----------+---------+
| f_name    | u_name  |
+-----------+---------+
| Peter     | John    |
| Jack      | John    |
| John      | Martin  |
| Peter     | Martin  |
| jack      | Martin  |
| Peter     | Barman  |
| John      | Jack    |
| Barman    | Jack    |
+-----------+---------+
```

I know, I need to use `JOIN` clause. But I don't know how should I do that correctly?

```
SELECT * FROM friends f
INNER JOIN users u
ON f.friend_id = u.id
```

Do I need another `JOIN`?

---

**Edited:** Can I get them in the same column and remove the duplicates? Like this: (I don't care about the order)

```
+-----------+
| f_name    |
+-----------+
| Peter     |
| Jack      |
| John      |
| Martin    |
| Barman    |
+-----------+
```

Actually I want a name list of everybody which exits into `friend` table *(either `friend_id` column or `user_id` column)*

Comment: You store both Jack/John and John/Jack. How come?

Comment: @jarlh It's valid in my database design.

Comment: Just because it's valid, you don't have to store it. My question remains, why do you store same friend combos twice?

Comment: @jarlh Because those two rows have different concepts. The first one means I've stored `Jack` as a specific user and `John` is one of his friends. And the second row means `John` is a specific user and `Jack` is one of his users. Both *user* and *friend* have different concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
SELECT u1.name AS f_name, u2.name AS u_name
FROM friends
    INNER JOIN users u1 ON friends.friend_id = u1.id 
    INNER JOIN users u2 ON friends.user_id = u2.id
```

To get the names of all `users` used in `friends` you can use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM users WHERE users.id IN (
    SELECT friend_id FROM friends 
    UNION 
    SELECT user_id FROM friends
)
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you, upvote. Just I cannot understand it. Can you please rewrite your query like this: `FROM friends ... JOIN users u1 ... JOIN users u2`. Is it possible?